# Specify single bar label color in simple pandas/matplotlib “barh” plot with one column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to change the label color of a single bar label in a pandas plot but somehow end up changing all label colors:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150

columns = ["Foo"]
data = [10.0, 201, 279]
index=["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns)

ax = df.plot(kind="barh", color="#00576B", rot=0, legend=False, align='center', width=0.5)
ax.set_title("My title")
ax.set_ylabel("")
ax.set_xlabel("Observation in MyUnit")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
for color, bar in zip(["#FBB900", "#00576B", "#00576B"], ax.patches):
    bar.set_color(color)
ax.set_xlim(0, 300)
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.2f')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.2f', color="red")  # this changes all label colors but I only want to change one
plt.show()
```

yields:

[image]

Any hints on how to control single label colors e.g. only for the second item?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ax.bar_label` returns a list of `Text` instances for the labels corresponding to heights of bars, we can store these `Text` instances in a variable then use indexing to select the `Text` instance for which you wish to change the color

```
tboxes = ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.2f')
tboxes[1].set_color('red') # changes color of label for Item 2
```

---

[image]